# How to debug chrome crash

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, crash

I'm developing a chrome extension to prettify an internal website, it works well in most cases. But some guys reports a bug, when moving a selected text area with mouse operation, chrome would suddently exit, issue could be reproduced again after chrome reboot, issue would disappear after uninstallation of my extension(not so sure about this as it's hard to reproduce).

Actually my extension would do nothing when moving text, so I have no idea how to fix it.

To root cause it, I suppose the straightforward way is to check chrome crash log. After web searching, some old post said, chrome_debug.log may help, but I could not find it anywhere in latest chrome version 112, is it depracated now?

How to debug the chrome crash issue? Thanks.

I tried to get log with following command, but didn't observe crash in console log.

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"   --enable-logging=stderr --v=1   > log111.txt 2>&1